# ASP.NET MVC Unhandled Exceptions on Images?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, http-status-code-404

I haven't been able to replicate the exception when I browse my site... but I found out about this through my event logger (it emails my cell phone when an unhandled exception occurs).

**Here's the exception:**

> The controller for path
>   '/Content/UsrImg/ImageFileName.jpg'
>   could not be found or it does not
>   implement IController.

What I think happened is that the image that Google (or perhaps a proxy server) had cached no longer existed. When trying to go directly to that image, it load the "Page not found" friendly error I wrote.

But should it be throwing an unhandled exception on 404 errors? Seems a bit strange to me. Perhaps there something I can do in the routing to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue yesterday.  Check to see if the image is on your server.  My problem was **Build Action** for the file was set to none, but it should be set to **Content**.  It was not including the file when I published the website.

You don't need to change routing, as the Content directory should be invoke Routing.